# Defining the standard programm to be opened when clicking links with href="tel:2131223"

Tags: html, windows, batch-file

I am looking for a solution to change the standard program which gets executed when you click a link like `<a href="tel:1231423">tel</a>`

Right now my machine opens it with skype. Is there a way to change the default program to the windows "dialer" ?

Comment: Your machine opens it with Skype because you have the Skype extension installed on your browser. Beyond that, you _might_ be able to throw something together with JavaScript. Maybe. Depends on if Dialer can take command line arguments, but I don't know about that. I honestly didn't realize people had used it in the last decade.

Comment: You can never chose the wishes of your customers :P